# Strange inequality character Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How can I change this character to this `!=` in Visual Studio for C#? Does someone know how to do it? Thanks a lot beforehand.

[image]

Sorry if it's not a properly question but I've not found any answer on the internet about how to do it.

Comment: Seems like you are using a custom font. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-change-fonts-and-colors-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022

To change the font.

Comment: @Link yep, it was that. I realized and changed it. Thanks for the comment!!

Comment: `≠` also means "not equal to", but as a single character - not that you can use this exact character. The font emulates this as a ligature

Comment: @HansKeﬆing I know it does the same function as '!=' but sometimes it confuses me and to my team at the moment of check some functionalities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Microsoft has developed a new font for developers called `Cascadia Code` and it has a number of features that replace multi-character language constructs to a visual representation called **Ligatures**. There are other "developer fonts" with similar features.

- https://monaspace.githubnext.com/
- https://github.com/microsoft/cascadia-code
- [https://www.slant.co/topics/5611/~monospace-fonts-with-programming-ligatures](https://www.slant.co/topics/5611/%7Emonospace-fonts-with-programming-ligatures)

Cascadia Code:

[image: cascadia code]

If you don't like these, you can switch back to `Cascadia Mono` (or another mono-spaced font without ligature support):

[image: Cascadia Mono]

[image]

In Visual Studio Code there is a configuration setting to disable ligatures:

```
"editor.fontLigatures": false
```

Unfortunately, Visual Studio 2022 and below do not have an option to configure whether (or which) ligatures are enabled.

Comment: I just realized that it's because my custom font. It converts the inequality character in that strange stuff. Anyway thanks a lot for the answer!! :))